How to invoke a cell magic inside a function?
Consider the following program, which I wrote in two Jupyter Notebook cells.
Cell 1:
import rumbledb as rmbl
%load_ext rumbledb
%env RUMBLEDB_SERVER=http://public.rumbledb.org:9090/jsoniq

Cell 2:
%%jsoniq
parse-json("{\"x\":3}}").x

After executing
spark-submit rumbledb-1.21.0-for-spark-3.5.jar serve -p 8001

in a Git Bash console, when I run these two cells in order, the output of the second cell is
Took: 0.2607388496398926 ms
3

How can I encapsulate the second cell in a function, say f, that I can call to thus: f()?
I tried the obvious:
Cell 3:
def f():
    %%jsoniq
    parse-json("{\"x\":3}}").x

Cell 4:
f()

Cell 3 ran successfully, however when I ran cell 4, I got the following error message:
UsageError: Line magic function `%%jsoniq` not found.

I then tried to move the %%jsoniq part to the beginning of the cell, as follows:
Cell 5:
%%jsoniq
def f():
    parse-json("{\"x\":3}}").x

However, running cell 5 yielded the following error message:
Took: 3.5366852283477783 ms
There was an error on line 3 in file:/home/ubuntu/:


Code: [XPST0003]
Message: Parser failed. 

Metadata: file:/home/ubuntu/:LINE:3:COLUMN:0:
This code can also be looked up in the documentation and specifications for more information.

I then tried to follow the advice given in the end of this answer, and ran the following cell:
Cell 6:
from IPython import get_ipython
def f():
    ipython = get_ipython()
    ipython.run_cell_magic('jsoniq', '', 'parse-json("{\"x\":3}}").x')

This executed without problem, but when I then ran cell 4 again (f()), I got the following error message:
Took: 0.5450258255004883 ms
There was an error on line 2 in file:/home/ubuntu/:


Code: [XPST0003]
Message: Parser failed. 

Metadata: file:/home/ubuntu/:LINE:2:COLUMN:0:
This code can also be looked up in the documentation and specifications for more information.

How can I encapsulate cell 2's code in a named function of my own making that I can later invoke in other cells?

Does the last solution work if you leave it outside a function?

@AndrewYim If I leave what outside what function? What does it mean to leave it outside a function?

As in, delete def f():, dedent the lines, and run the cell. I don't expect it to do much, but I thought it was worth mentioning at least.

@AndrewYim I get the exact same error as the last one I reported on in my post, if, in cell 6, I delete def f():, dedent the lines, and rerun the cell, except I get the error in response to running cell 6.

Then I don't think your problem is putting it into a function; something's likely wrong with the way you're using run_cell_magic. [Edit] this question or ask a new one to focus in on that one issue.

@AndrewYim https://stackoverflow.com/q/78767889/1818935

Indeed the %jsoniq magic is meant for interactive access.
However, it should be possible to create a Python function that does what you need if you copy-paste the code behind the %jsoniq magic as indicated here.
That way the Python function will fully encapsulate the communication with RumbleDB independently of the %jsoniq magic.
